# How to force regeneration of Twig templates?

Tags: 8, theming

[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org) generates classes for its templates. These classes are effectively caches by being written to disc.

Generally speaking, one probably doesn't need to bother with the details of how the twig templates are handled, but there could be cases when the Twig templates must be manually re-generated. (Similar to the need for the [Registry rebuild](https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) module in D7)

If it's relevant, I'm asking because I'm stuck with an error that looks like this:

> Fatal error: Class '__TwigTemplate_ddad913164239ac659c2bca09b3a49a5' not found in core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigEnvironment.php on line 107

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why you get that specific error, but have a look at drupal_flush_all_caches(), which does

```
PhpStorageFactory::get('twig')->deleteAll();
```

That said, I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, as I've never seen that error, not sure how it could end up expecting a class that is not there.

Comment: Interesting that you say you have never seen it, as I've seen it before as well. Then I just re-installed though, and it worked. Now not even that helps.

Comment: In this case, this turned out to be bad ownership of the settings file... Thanks for the helpful error message Drupal ;)

Comment: In my case it was the permissions of the public files folder that werent set correctly. I installed the website using drush, which in my local environment is a different user than the web server user. The solutions was to adjust the folder permissions.

Comment: Via drush: `drush ev '\Drupal\Core\PhpStorage\PhpStorageFactory::get("twig")->deleteAll();'`

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this Twig error in my error log, when attempting to access a Drupal 8.x site after it had been installed with drush with `drush si --db-url=mysql://root:root@localhost/mysite -y`. 
So to correct the issue, again with drush, simply clear the cache:

```
drush cr all
```

Additionally, after this, if your new Drupal 8.x site doesn't appear to have any CSS styles, then this is likely due to the apache/httpd user not having write permissions to sites/default/files.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore - you just need `drush cr`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
drush twig:compile
```

> `twig:compile` (`twigc`)          Compile all Twig template(s).